# OpenSSL Libraries with Quagga

Tags: ssl, openssl, bgp, quagga

We are looking to work with openSSL libraries within Quagga Open Source routing engine. However looking at the installation of openSSL I have, I can't see any .c files at all. Just a whole lot of .h files in /usr/include/openssl.

Also - I can't seem to find any information about what functions are required to 'build up' an TLS/SSL connection. I'm unsure on what functions to use. We are looking to implement Self-Signed certificates as it's out of scope to implement a CA for proper ceritificate authentication. This is just a proof of concept at this stage.

Any advice about this would be appreciated.

Regards,

Sarah

Comment: Quagga uses the SSL libraries installed on your system, you can check in /usr/lib/ for libssl...

Comment: If you want to look at the .c files on your machine, you should install openssl-devel package

Comment: Hi Dru - We are actually looking to implement SSL to protect BGP within the Quagga code. I've found something that looks promising here http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4822

Comment: Also - I have installed the development package, but still no .c files to be found. Only h files.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the source code of OpenSSL, you can download it from here: https://www.openssl.org/source/

If you want the exact source code your distribution package was built from, you need something like a source package, depending on what your distribution is.

As to being unsure of what OpenSSL functions to use to initiate a TLS connection, it has already been covered on SO.